# How can I create horizontal collection view with auto height in swift?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I created a horizontal collection view that calculates its own height, but the height is not calculated as desired.

My flowlayout and height constraint codes are as follows:

```
 if let flowLayout = collectionViewAppName.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
            flowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
            flowLayout.sectionInset = .init(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 32)
            flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 8
            flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        }

let height = collectionViewAppName.contentSize.height
collectionViewAppName.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height).isActive = true
```

Collection view cell class:

```swift
final class AppTypeCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
        @IBOutlet private weak var viewContainer: UIView!
        @IBOutlet private weak var stackViewContent: UIStackView!
        @IBOutlet private weak var imageViewAppLogo: UIImageView!
        @IBOutlet private weak var labelAppType: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet private weak var viewContainerOfImageView: UIView!
    
        override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()
            initViews()
        }
    
        private func initViews() {
            viewContainer.backgroundColor = .systemGray6
            labelAppType.font = UIFont.prepareGillSansSemiBoldFont(size: 15)
            viewContainer.clipsToBounds = true
            viewContainer.layer.cornerRadius = 16
            imageViewAppLogo.layer.cornerRadius = 8
            viewContainer.layer.borderColor = UIColor.Custom.foregroundColor.cgColor
            viewContainer.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
            imageViewAppLogo.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            imageViewAppLogo.clipsToBounds = true
        }
        
        func configure(with model: AppTypeCellModel) {
            let appType = model.appType
            imageViewAppLogo.image = appType.appLogo
            labelAppType.text = appType.appName
            if appType == .allApps {
                viewContainerOfImageView.isHidden = true
            }
        }
        
        func configureSelectedItem() {
            viewContainer.backgroundColor = UIColor.Custom.foregroundColor
            labelAppType.textColor = .black
        }
        
        func clearPreviousSelectedItem() {
            viewContainer.backgroundColor = .clear
            labelAppType.textColor = .label
        }
    
        override func prepareForReuse() {
            super.prepareForReuse()
            labelAppType.textColor = .label
            viewContainer.backgroundColor = .clear
            viewContainerOfImageView.isHidden = false
        }
    }
```

I achieved the height I wanted by giving it a fixed value, for example 55. I am attaching the result I wanted and a screenshot of the code I wrote.

So, what is the problem here?

[fixed 55 height constraint and the result I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpSU4.png)

[collection view automatic height calculation result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ff5UZ.png)

I use "contentsize" to calculate its own height, but it doesn't work as desired.

Answer (score 0):

A `UICollectionView` with flow layout arranges its cells based on the collection view frame size that ***YOU*** assign.

If you don't know the what the height of your cells will be when you setup the frame of the collection view (or if the cell height might change while the app is running), then you will need to calculate the cell height and update the collection view frame at run-time.

Comment: Thank you, but should I calculate the height of each collection view cell?
For example, I added "flowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 35, height: 35)", but the collection view does not look the way I wanted (it looks like the automatic height image I added). Actually I want to create horizontal collection view in single line.

Comment: @Aproachate - don't set the `.itemSize` ... set the collection view's height.

Comment: Should I use "size for item" function, can you tell me a little more about the path I should follow?

Comment: @Aproachate - in your post, you show a screen-cap of *"fixed 55 height constraint and the result I want"* ... If that gives you the result you want, why not use that?

Comment: Actually, I can use it, but I want to learn the exact right way. When i give it 55 height constraint, it looks a little big on devices like iPhone SE.

Comment: @Aproachate - do your want your ***cells*** (the rounded "tags") to change height, based on the device?

Comment: I actually want the collection view to calculate its own height. While the height may be 35 on the iPhone SE, it may be 55 on the iPhone 15 Pro Max, so I did not want to give a fixed height like 55.

Comment: @Aproachate - that doesn't make any sense... What is determining that it may be 35 or 55? The collection view ***content*** is not going to change its height, based on device. Do you have some code that is saying "cell height = 35 if iPhone SE, 55 if iPhone 15 Pro Max"?

Comment: @Aproachate - by that I mean: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LA97W.png

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I'm missing something regarding the collection view.

I initially gave the height value as 35 as an example, but then I noticed that it did not appear on a different device. I couldn't understand why this was happening. Therefore, I want it to draw the height as the cell's own height.

Comment: @Aproachate - you didn't answer my question ... Is your ***cell height*** going to be dynamic? Or, have you written code so you know your cell height? Edit your post and include your cell class.

Comment: It's not exactly a dynamic calculation, but I used auto layout. I edited my question, thank you very much.

Comment: @Aproachate - OK... you are designing your cell in Storyboard / Interface Builder. So you ***know*** the cell height. Set the collection view height to the same height as your cell.

Comment: The height of the cell appears to be 51, but since there is a label inside the cell, won't it have a different height on each device due to the font?

Comment: @Aproachate - no... **you**, the developer of the app, have designed the cell with a specific font **point size**, a "rounded border", and (I'm guessing) some top and bottom empty-space-padding... giving you a cell height of 51 **points**. That is not going to change based on device (unless you want it to, in which case you will write code to change it at run-time).